# AWS SDK for Java Tutorial sample missing classes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, classpath, aws-sdk

Following Getting Started with the **AWS SDK for Java** tutorial, to run the `AwsConsoleApp` sample:

```
java -cp .:/Users/marius/Dev/aws-java-sdk-1.3.8/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.3.8.jar AwsConsoleApp
```

I get the following issues:

```
===========================================
Welcome to the AWS Java SDK!
===========================================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.<clinit>(VersionInfoUtils.java:41)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:95)
    at AwsConsoleApp.init(AwsConsoleApp.java:93)
    at AwsConsoleApp.main(AwsConsoleApp.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 5 more
```

The same full SDK that was loaded in the classpath at compile time is given during runtime as well, so I can't figure out what's missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Among the [SDK prerequisites](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), you have:

> Requires **Apache Commons** (**Codec**, **HTTP Client**, and **Logging**) third-party packages, which are included in the third-party directory of the SDK.

so I just added them to my `.bashrc`:

```
#   Apache Commons Logging
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/marius/Dev/aws-java-sdk-1.3.8/third-party/commons-logging-1.1.1/*
#   Apache Commons HTTP Client
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/marius/Dev/aws-java-sdk-1.3.8/third-party/httpcomponents-client-4.1.1/*
#   Apache Commons Codec
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/marius/Dev/aws-java-sdk-1.3.8/third-party/commons-codec-1.3/*
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows add these paths to your system `CLASSPATH`

```
C:\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1\lib\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1.jar;
C:\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1\third-party\commons-logging-1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;
C:\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1\third-party\commons-codec-1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;
C:\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1\third-party\httpcomponents-client-4.1.1\httpclient-4.1.1.jar;
C:\aws-java-sdk-1.3.21.1\third-party\httpcomponents-client-4.1.1\httpcore-4.1.jar
```

then be sure to start with a new cmd prompt window after applying these.